# ACL wget permission denied

Tags: linux, file-permissions, wget, acl

`ls -la`:

```
total 0
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 root root 4096 Jul 11 21:40 ./
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root 4096 Jul 11 21:40 ../
```

the permissions on `.` have a plus so ACL is active...

`getfacl .`:

```
# file: .
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:package-maintainer:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

The package-maintainer group definitely has full access to this directory...

`groups`:

```
group1 group2 package-maintainer
```

I am definitely a member of package-maintainer group...

`wget` tarball:

```
--2022-07-11 22:08:26--  https://facstaff.susqu.edu/brakke/evolver/downloads/evolver-2.70.tar.gz
Resolving facstaff.susqu.edu (facstaff.susqu.edu)... 192.70.186.45
Connecting to facstaff.susqu.edu (facstaff.susqu.edu)|192.70.186.45|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3157309 (3.0M) [application/x-gzip]
evolver-2.70.tar.gz: Permission denied

Cannot write to 'evolver-2.70.tar.gz' (Success).
```

I already tried logging off and back on again. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ACL entries with `default:` only get copied to newly created items within the directory, but have no effect on the directory's own permissions. (In Windows terms, they are "Inherit-Only" entries.)

You need to add a second ACL entry for `group:package-maintainer:rwx` to define the effective permissions allowing you to create that file.